# jquery ui: drag and drop - mouse selection incorrect

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm working on a drag and drop navigation setup for my client.

I have the drag and drop working (in a basic form) however when you click on one of the list items to be dragged the actual droppable box is coming though at a different location.

It's a hard one to explain without showing you something so I have it online here: http://jsfiddle.net/elogicmedia/nVPYQ/7/

CSS FOR THE LI AND A TAGS

```
li {
color: black;
list-style: none;
padding: 1em 1em;
}
a {
position: absolute;
text-decoration: none;
border: 0px solid black;
width:98px;
height:98px;
border-radius:50%;
line-height:1.5em;
text-align:center;
    font-family: helvetica, arial;
    background-color: #C0D9D9;
}
```

JS DRAG AND DROPPABLE CODE

```
// let the gallery items be draggable
$( "li" ).draggable({
  revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
  containment: "document",
  helper: "clone",
  cursor: "move"
});  

// let the trash be droppable, accepting the gallery items
$( "#droparea" ).droppable({
  accept: "ul.gallery > li",
  activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
      alert('dropped');
    //deleteImage( ui.draggable );
  }
});
```

ALSO note the borders to the right of the fiddle, something is definaly not right there either. they shouldn't be there, just the circles. Screenshot from my jsfiddle setup below.

Thankyou

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working this out myself.

The working result is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/elogicmedia/nVPYQ/12/

I was trying to drop the LI tags but the A tags were the circles, the boxes to the right were the LI tags.

New Drag and Drop Code

```
// let the gallery items be draggable
$( "ul.gallery > li a" ).draggable({
  revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
  containment: "document",
  helper: "clone",
  cursor: "move"
});  

// let the trash be droppable, accepting the gallery items
$( "#droparea" ).droppable({
  accept: "ul.gallery > li a",
  activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
      alert('dropped');
    //deleteImage( ui.draggable );
  }
});
```